# How to implement 2D matrix using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am trying to implement a n x n 2D matrix using shell script. I am taking input for matrix elements using two for loop. But when I print the values after getting the elements using separate loop, It only prints last row n times. Please find below code and outputs.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the size of matrix: " n
c=`expr $n - 1`

# Get the matrix elements

for i in $(seq 0 1 $c)
do
        for j in $(seq 0 1 $c)
        do
                read -p "enter the value of $i, $j element " arr[$i,$j]
        done
done

# Print the matrix

for i in $(seq 0 1 $c)
do
        for j in $(seq 0 1 $c)
        do
                echo -n "${arr[$i,$j]} "
        done
        echo
done
```

Output:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-229:~/shellscript$ ./matrix.sh
Enter the size of matrix: 3
enter the value of 0, 0 element 1
enter the value of 0, 1 element 2
enter the value of 0, 2 element 3
enter the value of 1, 0 element 4
enter the value of 1, 1 element 5
enter the value of 1, 2 element 6
enter the value of 2, 0 element 7
enter the value of 2, 1 element 8
enter the value of 2, 2 element 9
7 8 9
7 8 9
7 8 9
```

As you can see, While printing output, It is printing last row in all the rows. Can someone please help me with this ?

Shell: BASH

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just store the data in a list and access element _(i,j)_ at index _i+k*j_, where _k_ is the number of columns?

Comment: "_I am trying to implement a n x n 2D matrix using shell script_" this very much feels like you're using the wrong tool for the job

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

Add `declare -A arr` before reading in the values in the loop and your code will work as you wish it to. But do read the longer version since you probably do not know what you are doing.

**Longer version**

**Bash does not support multi-dimensional arrays**.
What you are essentially creating here is called an *associative array* and you need to explicitly declare that the variable is an associative array for it to work. Hence the `declare -A arr`. For more information, you can read up [here](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays).

You can actually see how your array is getting modified by printing out the array after each input so that your inner loop will look something like :

```bsh
        for j in $(seq 0 1 $c)
        do
                read -p "enter the value of $i, $j element " arr[$i,$j]
                echo ${arr[*]}
        done
```

What we notice is that only 3 indices are created (for `n=3`), 0, 1 and 2 and the values at corresponding indices are replaced as the latter index `j` changes.

Without `declare -A` we're not creating an associative array, but a regular one indexed with integers. And that's where the issue lies. The index is taken as an arithmetic expression, and in arithmetic expressions, the comma operator evaluates both sides, but returns just the value of the right hand side.

Comment: Without `declare -A` they're not creating an associative array, but a regular one indexed with integers. And that's exactly the problem: when indexing one, the index is taken as an arithmetic expression, and in arithmetic expressions, the comma operator evaluates both sides, but returns just the value of the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @ilkkachu. Let me add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the size of matrix: " n
c=`expr $n - 1`

declare -A arr

# Get the matrix elements

for ((i=0;i<=c;i++))
do
        
    for ((j=0;j<=c;j++))
    do
        read -p "enter the value of $i, $j element " arr[$i,$j]
    done
done

# Print the matrix


for ((i=0;i<=c;i++))
do
    for ((j=0;j<=c;j++))
    do
            echo -n "${arr[$i,$j]} "
    done
    echo
done
```

**Result**:

```
$ ./matrix.sh 
Enter the size of matrix: 3
enter the value of 0, 0 element 1
enter the value of 0, 1 element 2
enter the value of 0, 2 element 3
enter the value of 1, 0 element 4
enter the value of 1, 1 element 5
enter the value of 1, 2 element 6
enter the value of 2, 0 element 7
enter the value of 2, 1 element 8
enter the value of 2, 2 element 9
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```